# Execute "SET ROLE" statement in eclipselink JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, database, vertica

I am using EclipseLink JPA to connect to vertica database and fetch results. Before running the below piece of code 
    EntityManager em = ...
    Query q = em.createQuery ("SELECT x FROM Table x");
    List results = q.getResultList ();

I need to first run the "SET ROLES ALL" statement for the user id. How to run such statements in JPA.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

for Vertica, you can do two things:

1. set your default role for the user:

   ```
   alter user myuser default role myrole;
   ```
2. use connection string property "ConnSettings" as described in the Vertica connection string docs (https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#13173.htm):

   > A string containing SQL statements that the JDBC driver automatically
   >   runs after it connects to the database. This property is useful to set
   >   the locale, set the schema search path, or perform other configuration
   >   that the connection requires.

   Your connection string could look like something like this:

   ```
   jdbc:vertica://myverticaserver/mydb?ConnSettings=SET+ROLE+myrole
   ```